# How to get Label into thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

First off let me show you my code:

Thread: http://pastebin.com/ie4WD5W8

Then to call the thread i used the following...

```
    randomKeyGen key1 = new randomKeyGen(ranLKey);
    key1.start();
```

ranLKey is my label and I can't figure out why it won't work. As long as I do not try to put a label in the thread it works, but that defeats the entire purpose. So the above code does **NOT** work, but the code from [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ie4WD5W8) seems to be fine. Hopefully you can help me out with what I am doing wrong.

I am using netbeans if that helps at all. Also talked about this before in multiple places. So if you saw me before, then just letting you know I am still looking for help.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: "public class randomKeyGen extends Thread implements Runnable" - I do not know, why do you want to do both the way? either you can use any of that right? extends Thread is direct way of extending the thread, then remove implements Runnable interface.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue might be in the *mainFrame*'s *setKey(String)* and/or *getKey()* calls. Aren't they play with something in GUI? If so they should go through event dispatch thread, similar to the label setting (try *invokeAndWait(Runnable)*). What's more it's advised to check first for the event dispatch thread before creating a new runnable (*isEventDispatchThread()*).